# Как зафиксировать заголовок таблицы при прокрутке?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Есть таблица в контейнере с жёстко заданной высотой. При большом количестве строк в таблице у окружающего блока появляется полоса прокрутки. Однако имеется проблема - заголовок таблицы уезжает наверх, и его не видно. Как зафиксировать его, чтобы он всегда был виден наверху блока?

Я пытался назначить ему вот такие CSS свойства, но видимого результата нет.

```
thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Какие есть способы решения проблемы? Желательно обойтись без разбиения таблицы не две, т.к. в таком случае могут разойтись столбцы.

Для удобства вот пример моей вёрстки.

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Заголовок1</th>
        <th>Заголовок2</th>
        <th>Заголовок3</th>
        <th>Заголовок4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению, сейчас `position: sticky` [практически нигде не поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky), поэтому данный ответ не очень полезный :(

Судя по [этому ответу на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169520/5812238) из-за [бага](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=702927) в Chrome, свойство `position: sticky` нужно присваивать не заголовку таблицы (`thead`), а ячейкам этого заголовка (`th`). Ну и ещё стоит добавить к ним белый фон. Примерно так:

```
thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

Сниппет:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Заголовок1</th>
        <th>Заголовок2</th>
        <th>Заголовок3</th>
        <th>Заголовок4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Признаться честно, в Firefox значительных изменений не наблюдается - заголовок таблицы продолжает прокручиваться вместе с остальными строчками. Возможности проверить в Chromium (или даже в Chrome) пока нету.

Comment: @mymedia ну да, в Firefox `position: sticky` [не поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) :(

Comment: и точно, для таблиц не работает :(

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать, такое решение, только придется фиксировать ширину колонк таблицы.

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 } 
 
 
table td:nth-child(1), 
table th:nth-child(1) { min-width: 150px; text-align: left }
 
table td:nth-child(2),
table th:nth-child(2) { min-width: 150px; text-align: left}
 
table td:nth-child(3),
table th:nth-child(3) { min-width: 100px; text-align: left}

table td:nth-child(4),
table th:nth-child(4) { width: 100px; text-align: left}

table  thead {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FDFDFD;   
  }
  
table thead tr {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
}

table tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;   
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Заголовок1</th>
        <th>Заголовок2</th>
        <th>Заголовок3</th>
        <th>Заголовок4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

2022 год:
в chrome и firefox работает простое css

```
th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: -3px; // при нуле в chrome остаётся странный зазор
  z-index: 2;
}
```